# Is it possible to bottom align a floated div?

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I want to avoid using `position: absolute;` because I want to keep the functionality where when the parent container shrinks, the divs position themselves one under the other, instead of overlapping.

```css
#container {
    border:1px solid;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

#right {
    float:right;
    background:blue;
}

ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul li {
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <ul>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I've updated the code sample to more closely resemble what my own actually looks like. Unfortunately I'm not working with fixed widths/heights, though for this particular problem, the red div can have a fixed width/height.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdL60bLu/10/

Basically, I'd like the blue div to be aligned to the bottom right, and when the window size shrinks, to keep the functionality of the blue div moving below the red div, which doesn't happen with position absolute.

Is this doable?

Comment: Does either div have fixed (pixel or percent) width and/or height?

Comment: @SalmanA Red div has a max-width in px, and then a width of 50%. Blue div is the menu, would adjust its width/height based on content.

Comment: If you don't want to use `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` between these two divs, then there is no other way since you want to have this two divs stacked one below another, while they should be in the same line when the screen is not to narrow. One is opposite to another. I think it's OK to use position:absolute and then either set min-height on parent element or use media-queries to switch position:absolute to float as certain screen width

Answer (score 2):

This layout can be done with flexbox.

It fulfills both your requirements:

- The blue div is aligned to the bottom right and
- When the window size shrinks, the blue div moves below the red div

  Except that when you set `display:flex` on a container, floats have no effect on the items. [so if you like you can even leave the `float:left;` and `float:right` on the left and right elements - but know that they do nothing]

  > Note that float, clear and vertical-align have no effect on a flex
  >   item.

  ([CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zdL60bLu/12/) (Resize to see the effect)

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  /* redundant */
  background: blue;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but it works: Give the right container a margin-top of the height of the left container minus the height of the right container (in this case, 50px). Then give the left container a negative margin-bottom of the same amount (-50px). Here is it working: http://jsfiddle.net/zdL60bLu/9/

Code added:

```
#left {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#right {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer unfortunately my blue div doesn't actually have a fixed width/height, I just simplified the code snippet, which maybe I shouldn't have. I've updated the code and fiddle. I might end up just using media queries for this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See Danield's answer below. It looks like he/she figured it out.